# Не запускается docker на unix

Tags: python, docker, python-2.x, unix, виртуальная-машина

Я использую облачные вычисления,
и на виртуальную машину установил docker:
командная строка:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt install docker.io
```

и запустил его:

```
sudo service docker start
sudo service docker enable
```

```
 * Starting Docker: docker
   ...done.
Usage: service docker {start|stop|restart|status}
```

сам я не разбираюсь в этой технологии и она мне нужна только для сборки чужого python-проекта:

```
cd im2txt_demo
make build
```

build использует Makefile:

```
name = im2txt_demo 

build:
    docker build . -t $(name)

stop:
    docker rm -f $(name) || true

run: stop
    docker run -it --rm=true -p 8888:8888 -v $(shell pwd):/root --name=$(name) $(name) bash -l
start: stop
    docker run -it --rm=true -p 8888:8888 -v $(shell pwd):/root --name=$(name) $(name) run_jupyter.sh -l
```

что после запуска выдает:

```
/content/im2txt_demo
docker build . -t im2txt_demo 
Cannot connect to the Docker daemon at unix:///var/run/docker.sock. Is the docker daemon running?
Makefile:4: recipe for target 'build' failed
make: *** [build] Error 1
```

Как я понимаю у меня проблемы с запуском docker,
 
я пытался использовать:

```
sudo start docker 
sudo enable docker
```

на что ответ:

```
"docker start" requires at least 1 argument.
See 'docker start --help'.

Usage:  docker start [OPTIONS] CONTAINER [CONTAINER...]

Start one or more stopped containers
docker: 'enable' is not a docker command.
See 'docker --help'
```

Я искал в интернете, но ответа на мою ситуацию я так и не нашел, а разбираться с темой docker и контейнеров docker широко я не собирался.
Я бы не отказался от нескольких советов, а лучше кода который поможет мне построить проект.

Answer (score 0):

`sudo systemctl enable --now docker`и `systemctl status docker` что говорят? Вы похоже просто не стартанули сервис.

Comment: Synchronizing state of docker.service with SysV service script with /lib/systemd/systemd-sysv-install.
Executing: /lib/systemd/systemd-sysv-install enable docker
System has not been booted with systemd as init system (PID 1). Can't operate.
System has not been booted with systemd as init system (PID 1). Can't operate.

Comment: Можете точнее определить что Вы имеете в виду под "стартануть сервис" - это что-то в духе "systemctl start docker"? Не могли бы Вы дать совет или код как все таки его запустить.

Comment: @anonymous Да `sudo systemctl start docker` это именно запуск сервиса docker.

Comment: Я использую service так как для systemctl оно пишет: System has not been booted with systemd as init system (PID 1). Can't operate. И я попытался сделать что-то на подобии https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52197246/system-has-not-been-booted-with-systemd-as-init-system-pid-1-cant-operate

Comment: @anonymous Надо-же. У кого-то в 2k20 году ещё остались системы не на systemd... Ну тогда да -- `service start docker`